# За сколько дней в среднем на вопрос даётся правильный ответ?

Tags: обсуждение, принятые-ответы

За сколько дней в среднем на вопрос даётся правильный ответ?

Comment: Пока существуют вопросы без ответов, среднее значение всегда будет бесконечное число дней. Если вместо среднего попытаться посчитать медианное значение (с предположением, что принятый ответ является правильным), то из-за того, что 52% вопросов не имеют принятого ответа, получается, что медианное значение всё равно те же самые бесконечное число дней.

Comment: Если считать только вопросы с принятыми ответами, то медианное время появления принятого ответа — 1 час 1 минута 1 секунда.

Comment: @andreymal Больше похоже на ответ, чем на комментарии)

Answer (score -3):

***Краткий ответ:*** Взаимозависимости от темы вопроса.

---

Я не видел, чтоб на вопрос отвечали более 5 дней. Мне обычно отвечают в тот-же день. Иногда на следующий.

---

Если метка вопроса популярна, то шанс, что на вопрос быстрее ответят становится больше.

Comment: "Я не видел, чтоб на вопрос отвечали более 5 дней" - сейчас 66674 вообще без ответов, самые старые - с 2011 года, т.е. почти с начала существования ХэшКода/RU.SO: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=answers%3A0+closed%3Ano .

Comment: @insolor Ну сложные вопросы значит. Я говорю про те которые просто ждут экспертов. У меня у самого вопрос уже пару месяцев без ответов висит.

Answer (score -4):

Примерно 1--2 дня хватает на нормальный ответ. (2 дня только иногда, когда вопрос требует долгой дискусии и\или долго будут поступать ответы (считая вопросы с ответами)).